# Как интегрировать ИИ и tg бота через python?

Tags: python, telegram, искусственный-интеллект

Всем привет! Есть задача, разработать tg бота, который будет делать определенный запрос по параметрам к ИИ и выдавать персональную тренировку.

Облазил почти весь интернет, но не могу найти способ связи бота и ИИ. Из-за того, что, openai заблокирован, приходится искать нестандартные способы (способ с vpn не подходит). Пытался через парсинг сайта, через meta.com, albato, dialogflow(он не подходит, из-за длительности обучения), но нигде не могу сделать нормального работоспособного бота. Нужно, чтобы запросами к ИИ, можно было писать через интерпретатор. То есть, грубо говоря, мне нужен аналог API, как у openai, доступный в СНГ странах.

Может кто-то знает еще способы связи бота и ИИ (желательно с бесплатным сервисом, или с пробным периодом)?

Comment: Да, вопрос интересный.

Comment: Можно конечно порассуждать о том, что можно "на собственном железе модели запускать", но по моему накладно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй использовать библиотеку [transformers](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/index) от Hugging Face.
И сегодня наткнулся на [статью](https://pikabu.ru/story/zapusk_analogov_chatgpt_na_domashnem_pk_v_paru_klikov_i_s_interfeysom_10697114?utm_source=andlinkshare&utm_medium=sharing) по запуску аналогов ChatGPT локально.